# How to stop my firefox extension which interferes other extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have tried very hard to make my extension as simple as possible, it now do not contain any skin/css, it just have 'statusbar' in one single 'overlay'.

The issue is that when installed, it hides the top three icon of 'all-in-one toolbar' extension of my firefox 3.6.3.

On other two machine which do not have 'all-in-one toolbar', it hide all the icons of the web-development toolbar!

chrome.manifest

```
content     stackoverflow    content/
content     stackoverflow    content/ contentaccessible=yes

overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://stackoverflow/content/browser.xul

locale  stackoverflow   en-US   locale/en-US/
```

browser.xul

```
<overlay id="dch-browser-overlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
        <script type="application/x-javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"/>
        <script src="stackoverflow.js" />

        <statusbar id="status-bar">
            <statusbarpanel id="stackoverflow-status-bar-icon" class="statusbarpanel-iconic" src="chrome://stackoverflow/content/icon_small.png" tooltiptext="&runstackoverflow;" onclick="stackoverflow.run()" />
        </statusbar>
</overlay>
```

I have tried very hard to simplify the extension to find the reason, but failed, any suggestion/ideas would be welcome.

thx.

Comment: Hard to answer without some screenshots and code, I think.

Comment: I have put the core code as above, if you need any other information, please let me know...

Comment: I would assume that "status-bar" isn't unique. Try changing it's name to to "stackoverflow-status-bar".

Comment: Hi ChirsF, 
thank you for your suggestion, as I think the statusbar id is required to be something like that in order for firefox to load it?
Some other extension like GreaseMonkey use the same id, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the code for the web developer toolbar, I'd say that it's the id on your overlay ("dch-browser-overlay") that is non-unique.

Side note: you really *really* shouldn't be loading jQuery from the web in the browser.  Package it in your extension (in your case, it's going to slow startup down a bunch *and* present a security hole if you are MITMd).

Comment: Totally agree! Loading JavaScript from the Internet inside an extension is VERY DANGEROUS, you are giving that JavaScript full privileges on your computer (read, write and execute)! Also, loading libraries directly in the XUL (even if coming from inside the extension) is a problem because it pollutes the global namespace and potentially conflicts with other extensions and even the Firefox code.

Comment: I agree with the jQuery comment, I just wondering whether the browser would cache the script for extension if already loaded by front end?
will change according to suggestion.

about the confliction, as my web developer toolbar is still working (where my 'all-in-one toolbar' is conflicted) my friend's web developer toolbar is hidden (all icon not show) where he does not have the 'all-in-one' toolbar...

Comment: It would likely cache it, if there is space (disk cache is small).  Local file access is still going to be faster.  Conflicts in ids can cause weird issues where one will "win" and strange things happen to the others.  That is likely your issue (even if it isn't the particular id I cited).